# Did I integrate correctly? Integration using algebraic substitution.

Tags: integration

> Integrate with respect to $x$
>   $$\int3{\sec^2(3x)\tan(3x)dx}$$

There's 2 ways of doing this according to the book, I just wish to know if I did both ways correctly...please correct me on where I went wrong

Method 1:

$$3\int{\sec^2(3x)\tan(3x)dx}$$
$u=3x;\dfrac{1}{3}du=dx$
$$3\int{\dfrac{\sec^2(3x)\tan(3x)}{3}du}$$
$$\int{\sec^2(3x)\tan(3x)du}$$
$v=sec(3x);\dfrac{dv}{sec(3x)}=\tan(3x)du$
$$\int{\dfrac{\sec^2(3x)dv}{\sec(3x)}}$$
$$\int{\sec(3x)dv}$$
$$\dfrac{1}{2}\sec^2(3x)+C$$

Method 2:

$$3\int{\sec^2(3x)\tan(3x)dx}$$
$u=3x;\dfrac{1}{3}du=dx$
$$3\int{\dfrac{\sec^2(3x)\tan(3x)}{3}du}$$
$$\int{\sec^2(3x)\tan(3x)du}$$
$v=\tan(3x);dv=\sec^2(3x)du$
$$\int{\tan(3x)dv}$$
$$\dfrac{1}{2}{\tan^2(3x)}+ C$$

Comment: note that :$\int sec u du \neq sec^2u\\\int tan(x)dx \neq \frac{1}{2}tan^x$

Comment: @daryakhosrotash It was $\int \sec^2(3x) dv$, which is, more properly, $\int v dv$.

Comment: Ughh, that's horrid notation...

Comment: @Mike your comment is very unhelpful, please comment with something constructive like everyone else, you have to remember that there are people in the world still learning this material, and may make mistakes in notation, in future comment with corrections.

Comment: Understanding the concepts is the most important, and it takes time to learn how to write the answers neatly and elegantly. It may be worth mentioning that, when we do substitution, we usually replace all the original variable by the new variable.

Comment: @Modrisco SRX had already beaten me to the answer.  But how in the world can you integrate something in 2 variables?  At the very least, you invite misperceptions like in darya's comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both answers are correct. In fact you can differentiate your answers with respect to $x$ to see it gives the integrand to check your answer.

For your interest, your two answers are equivalent because
$$\frac{1}{2} \sec^2(3x) + C_1= \frac{1}{2}(\tan^2(3x) + 1)+C_1 = \frac{1}{2}\tan^2(3x) +C_2$$

Comment: Are my methods okay though?

Comment: The methods are okay.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int 3sec^2(3x)tan(3x)dx$$ use this substitution :$$u=tan(3x)\\du=3(1+tan^(3x)dx=3sec^2(3x)dx\\3sec^2(3x)tan(3x)dx=3sec^2(3x)dx *tan(3x)=\\du *u$$so $$\int 3sec^2(3x)tan(3x)dx=\int udu=\frac{1}{2}u^2=\\\frac{1}{2}tan^2(3x) +const$$

Answer (score 1):

You should write like this:

$$3\int{\sec^2(3x)tan(3x)dx}$$

put $u=3x;\dfrac{1}{3}du=dx$

$$3\int{\dfrac{\sec^2(u)tan(u)}{3}du}$$

Put $v=sec(u);\dfrac{dv}{sec(u)}=\tan(u)du$

$\int{vdv}=\frac{v^2}{2}+c$, Now replacing back the values,we have the final solution as,  $$\dfrac{1}{2}\sec^2(3x)+C$$

Method2: $$3\int{\sec^2(3x)tan(3x)dx}$$

put $u=3x;\dfrac{1}{3}du=dx$

$$3\int{\dfrac{\sec^2(u)tan(u)}{3}du}$$

$v=\tan(u);dv=\sec^2(u)du$

$\int{vdv}=\frac{v^2}{2}+c$, Now replacing back the values,we have the final solution as, $$\dfrac{1}{2}{\tan^2(3x)}+ C$$